# CompareAttribute always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, compare-attribute

I have an auto-generated partial class for my model, I've extended it by creating a metadata class that decorates the fields/properties with metadata and attributes. I've added another partial class so I can give it a string property of email, but I dont want that stored in the db. I only want to use it to compare to the first entry for validation/comparision however the view always returns the error message stating that theyre not the same regardless of input.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeesMetadata))]
[DisplayColumn("FullName")]
public partial class Employees
{
    [CompareAttribute("EmailAddress")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeesMetadata
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not too sure why the compare is always false.

Comment: Get rid of those partial classes and use a view model containing properties `public string EmailAddress { get; set; }` and `[CompareAttribute("EmailAddress")] public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }`. Base you view on the the view model and when you post, if `ModelState` is valid, map the view models `EmailAddress` property to the data model. And you can then add extra validation attributes such as `[EmailAddress]` etc.

Comment: I have to use the partial class because I use the employeemetadata which is heavily decorated with attributes. I only posted the relevant fields that is why. In the model i have Email but not confirm email, which is why i've got it in the partial class. Any idea how this can be tackled via the current methods.

Comment: _I have to use the partial class_? **No your don't!**. Use a view model - its the properties in the view model which get decorated with validation atributes